# No such file or directory when using rosrun?

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Diamondback on Maverick Meerkat Ubuntu. Basically the problem is that when I rosrun a particular node (State_Machine.py), I just get a " ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory " error.

I can rosrun other files in the directory, so it's definitely in my package path. The permissions are set correctly (chmod +x worked). I have "#!/usr/bin/env python" at the top of my file. I ran it on a friend's computer (who also has ROS setup), and it threw the same error for him, so it wouldn't seem to be my Linux/python. Renaming it doesn't fix the problem. Commenting out the imports doesn't help. It's been "make"d many times now. All to no avail.

I can post the code if that would help, but it's rather long, and it's not even getting to the main (doesn't do a print).

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10412/no-such-file-or-directory-when-using-rosrun?/) by [Sam Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/759/sam-powers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-30**:
Can you put a minimal python script in the same location as the script in question. Just the #! and a printout. If that rosruns (what I'd expect) its some problem in your code.

**Comment by [Sam Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/759/sam-powers/) on 2011-06-30**:
When I run /usr/bin/env python: Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 16:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > 

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-29**:
what happens when you execute: /usr/bin/env python?

**Comment by [Sam Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/759/sam-powers/) on 2011-06-28**:
Oh, yes, I should have mentioned that. I can do "python State_Machine.py" and it runs fine. (EDIT: Actually, I need permission to post the code, so I have to get that first.)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-27**:
Can you just run the node from the command line?  rosrun is just a bash script which is like roscd PACKAGE && ./path_to_script  Where it does some nice tab completion on executables.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-06-27**:
Can you put your code on github or the like so that I can take a look at it?

**Comment by [Tatsat](https://answers.ros.org/users/72598/tatsat/) on 2021-04-08**:
Hello, this is not working for me. C++ files work without problem. Issue is only with python files. I made the file executable with chmod +x talker.py .....(I am a beginner), added the #!/usr/bin/env python in the file, and also converted from DOS to UNIX. It still does not work for me. It specifically cannot find python files. ERROR :  /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory ...... I am using ROS Noetic, and VS Code platform.

**Comment by [Tatsat](https://answers.ros.org/users/72598/tatsat/) on 2021-04-08**:
So, the problem got solved. I ran: sudo apt-get install python-is-python3     ....I cannot figure out how it got figured out. It had something to do with installation of python 3. I installed ROS Noetic but I did not specifically installed Python 3. So maybe the problem was there..LOL. BTW thanks to this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/942930/usr-bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory   I found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My coworker figured out the answer. It was a DOS text file, not a UNIX text file. Converting it fixed the problem, and it was able to be rosrun.

I have no idea why it was a DOS text file, but at least it works now.

---

Originally posted by [Sam Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/759/sam-powers/) with karma: 116 on 2011-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-03-11**:
yea this happened to me, i wrote the file in windows pyscripter and i guess the encoding was different, re-writing the file worked

**Comment by [Gullydwarf](https://answers.ros.org/users/7076/gullydwarf/) on 2013-09-25**:
To be precise, it is the line endings which create this problem. DOS/Windows '/r/n' do not work, only UNIX line endings '/n' work.
Not the file encoding.

You can probably change the line endings setting in your editors preferences or buffer options. If not, use another editor :)

**Comment by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on 2016-02-05**:
Fantastic!  Even though this thread is dated, I was able to find it and solve this issue.  Kudos!  Searched for two days for a solution and this tip finally enabled a driver that was written in python.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to make State_Machine.py executable.

```
chmod +x State_Machine.py
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/759/sam-powers/) on 2011-06-30**:
I did that. Everyone who's looked at my problem has too. It doesn't help.